# Return response to caller when one of the async call is done

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I need to save file in two different server using .net api.Its asp.net Core web api. I want to return the response to the caller when saving the file in any of the server is succeeded. Could this be achieved using async programming? Can we return the response from api and let it save at other location?

For now I am using Parallel option:

```
   var imageName = $"{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}.{extension}";

        var locations = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

        Parallel.ForEach(destinationFolders, folder =>
        {

            try
            {
                var fullName = $@"{folder.Value}\{imageName}";

                if (!Directory.Exists(folder.Value))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(folder.Value);

                var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(content);
                using (var imageFile = new FileStream(fullName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    imageFile.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    imageFile.Flush();
                }

                locations.TryAdd(folder.Key, Regex.Replace(folder.Value, @"\\", @"\"));

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logging.Log.Error($"{Constants.ExceptionOccurred} : {ex.Message} against {folder.Key} Value : {Regex.Replace(folder.Value, @"\\", @"\")}");

            }
        });
```

However the problem here is I am making it to wait while it finishes saving in both the location and return the response.

Comment: Is [Task.WaitAny](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitany?view=netframework-4.7.2) something you are searching for?

Comment: @5ar : I need to do some post processing as well when saving the file to the second server/location fails. Yes I was looking similar on the lines of Task.Waitany. I would be ever grateful to you if you can point me to some tutorial/ step by step  guide on this.

Comment: What kind of application is this? You need to provide us with more details.

Comment: Its asp.net Core web api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not appear to need Task Parallel for this. Consider the following truly asynchronous approach. Also note, you only need to do the Base64 decode once.

```
public Task WriteFiles(IEnumerable<string> destinationFolders, string content)
{
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(content);
    IList<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var folder in destinationFolders)
    {
        // <snipped>

        Func<Task> taskFactory = async () =>
        {
            using (var imageFile = new FileStream(fullName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await imageFile.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                await imageFile.FlushAsync();
            }
        };

        tasks.Add(taskFactory());

        // <snipped>
    }

    return Task.WhenAny(tasks);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much , yeah it looks pretty neat specially conversion thing !! However I have another thing to do if the later task(unfinished one) fails then I need to do some post processing. How can I capture that ?I mean response from second save.

Comment: Here from 'fail' I meant: it was unable to save on file server